# TeXShop saving several unwanted files

Tags: texshop, auxiliary-files

Every time I save a file (having previewed it) in TeXShop, it saves five different files (.aux, .log, .pdf, .synctex.gz, and .tex). Is there a way to change the setting so that it only saves the .tex file? Or the .tex file and .pdf file?

Comment: Well there is the option of removing the auxiliary files after compilation from `File->Remove Aux Files...`

Comment: @Jeroen `Tools->Clean Auxiliary Files...`

Answer (score 1):

`.log` and `.aux` files are produced by `TeX` or `LaTeX` and are very important. You will see it, making more complicated documents. For example, the `.aux` file is useful when creating bibliographies.

Generally they a small, so there's no need of removing them during the work on a document.